# Thumbnail issues for slideshow

Tags: jquery, fancybox, thumbnails, slideshow

I am trying to use FancyBox in order to display a gallery I'm inputting into my web layout. I'm using a 3-column layout, and I'm trying to figure out how to input my thumbnail images in the third column. I want them lined up in an organized fashion, so I was giving them an auto width and a specified height. It seemed to work fine, however all of the sudden the second thumbnail doesn't line up with the first thumbnail. When I use firebug and hover over the images, it shows that there is space above the second thumbnail that is designated for the href part for some reason. What do I do to fix this? And is there any way that I can make the thumbnails all the same size without distorting the proportions of the thumbnail image? I've been struggling to find a plugin that creates a simple pop out gallery, and this one is the first one I've found that works, but I am just having tiny problems.

The link is:
http://kunkelgroup.com/webpage/kunkelsquare.html

Answer (score 0):

The way you arrange your thumbnails has nothing to do with Fancybox. Your layout problem seems to be more a CSS issue than anything else. You may re-tag your question and add CSS, you may get quicker help.

Additionally, I would advice you to re-size your thumbnails with an image editor instead of re-sizing them dynamically via html; doing the second may impact dramatically the performance and page load.

On the other hand, you may try http://masonry.desandro.com/ plugin to arrange your thumbnails.